# Searching for a String in a text file

Tags: c#, if-statement, for-loop

Hello I'm trying to search for the word "Jeep" located in my text file. I have my constructor class to get and set items. I use a for loop to cycle through all the cars and the if statement to look for the word "Jeep". If there are any like that it will take the mileage of all Jeeps and pop up in a message box. But I do not think the word search is working. Thank you!

```
private void btnJeep_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double jeepMile = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i > cars.Count; i++)
    {
        if (cars[i].Make == "Jeep")
        {
            jeepMile = cars[i].Mileage;
        }
    }
    MessageBox.Show("The average mileage of all the jeeps is: " + jeepMile, "Jeep Mile Avg.", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging? What's the value of `cars[i].Make` at any iteration? What's in `cars`?

Comment: your for loop is wrong. The 2 section should be true for the loop to continue, not for the loop to exit.

Comment: It is just a String to return the Make of cars, like Jeep, Ford, Toyota etc. Cars is my list of 10 objects.

Comment: If you would step through with your debugger you would see that your for loop is not executing. Please learn how to use the debugger so you can understand what is going on here.

Comment: once again eddie_cat this is a case of someone not listening to what others can definitely see right off the bat..

Comment: THANK YOU Guillaume!!! I would've never tried that! Is there anyway to give you points or something? You too Eddie

Comment: that's true too but seasoned coders such as ourselves, I personally noticed it right off the bat

Comment: this could all be reduced to one line of LINQ

Comment: Jonesy that's true..but the op must understand the basics of .NET / C# before even attempting to code something more complex

Comment: 1. I see no text file here 2. you just keep the last `Mileage`, this won't work for an average (need sum and count).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change:
    for (int i = 0; i > cars.Count; i++)
To:
     for (int i = 0; i < cars.Count; i++)